# how to force the ag-grid to scroll to the selected/highlighted row position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, ag-grid

We are using `ag-grid` and I need to display the scrollbar in child window as per selected row position in `ag-grid`. Please find the below plunkr and click on `source_id` which is an edit page and I need to show the scroll bar as per selected/highlighted row on window popup screen.

In my code scroll bar is working but it is not showing exact scroll bar position as per selected/highlighted row in child window. And please provide inputs for to show the scrollbar in child window as per selected/highlighted row position using `ag-grid`.

[Plunkr url](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/kdsFTzUhA0kEd6WI?open=lib%2Fscript.js&preview)

Note: It has to scroll automatically like selected row position in 'ag-body-viewport' div class.

Follow the below steps:

```
1)In plunker click on preview button.
2)Click on any source_id in ag-grid.
3)Once click the source_id popup window will be displayed.
4)In popup window another grid will be displayed with highlighted row with respective of   source_id.
5)My query is like in this particular window ,how to scroll the scroll bar automatically as per highlighted/selected row postition .
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the [scrolling section of ag-grid api](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#scrolling) you'll get an idea how to get about it.

You could update your getRowStyle function to something like this:

```
  function getRowStyle(params) {
    ....
      if (params.data.source_id.trim() === $scope.source_id.trim()) {
        colorToReturn = {
          'background-color': 'orange'
        };
        $scope.gridOption.api.ensureIndexVisible(Number(params.data.source_id));
      }
    ....
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Approach with Angular 8 and ag-grid 20.2(enterprise)-

```
scrollToSelectedRow(){
this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes()[0].rowIndex,null);}
```

ensureIndexVisible takes 2 parameters i.e. rowIndex(integer) and position('top','bottom',null etc).
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#scrolling

Comment: clean solution,worked for me ...

Answer (score 0):

Though it is too late to reply, considering it might be helpful for someone working on Angular.

```js
goToSelected() {
    let addedNode :any []= Object.values(this.gridApi.getModel().getCopyOfNodesMap())
        .filter(//logic to fetch row on which you want to scroll to)
    if(addedNode !==null && addedNode !=undefined && addedNode.length >0){
      let toBeFocused:number = addedNode[0].rowIndex;
      this.gridApi.setFocusedCell(toBeFocused, 0);
      this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(toBeFocused);
      this.gridApi.getRowNode(toBeFocused).setSelected(true, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I select a particular agGrid row, and make sure it's visible, using Angular & agGrid v23:

```
  let IDofRowToSelect = 123;

  this.gridApi.forEachNode((node) => {
      node.setSelected(node.data.id == IDofRowToSelect);
      if (node.data.id == IDofRowToSelect) {
          this.gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(node.rowIndex, 'middle');
      }
  });
```